# How to reset state variables in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, theano, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am building an RNN (LSTM/GRU) and I have time series of variable lengths.  How can I reset the state variable after each time series is done?  I would like to do this in Keras, but if I have to build an RNN in Theano (my back-end) that's fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't in Keras' documentation but recurrent layers have a .reset_state() function.  You can find it on the github and you can either reset the states of one layer or the entire model.

Answer (score 2):

In Keras Documentation, [Chapter on Recurrent Layers](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/):

> To reset the states of your model, call .reset_states() on either a specific layer, or on your entire model.

E.g.:

```
model.predict()

model.reset_states()
```